Data loss occurs during CnosDB upgrade
Data loss occurs during CnosDB upgrade
In the process of using CnosDB, I upgraded to the latest version 2.3 through version 2.3.5, and found that some data was lost.

load data by load_cnosdb(there are 2 tables: diagnostics and  readings)
cat cnosdb-2023-01-03-16-17-data.gz | gunzip|load_cnosdb --urls "http://192.168.0.24:9902" --workers 10 --db-name "benchmark001"


version: cnosdb 2.3.5, revision 3fa5ee033ad3515f2bd01fb11d87c7fee7601ebe

check the diagnostics count(*)
benchmark ❯ select count(*) from diagnostics;
+-----------------+
| COUNT(UInt8(1)) |
+-----------------+
| 1296544         |
+-----------------+
Query took 238.098 seconds.3.




upgrade CnosDB to latest version: cnosdb 2.3.5, revision 243891bcb1c5690a4dbdd2fe721090b826934357

check the diagnostics count(*)

benchmark ❯ select count(*) from diagnostics;
+-----------------+
| COUNT(UInt8(1)) |
+-----------------+
| 1296540         |
+-----------------+
Query took 211.359 seconds.



Has anyone encountered similar problems?

The reason was that some indexes were lost during the upgrade process, this issue has been fixed
